# Question about reversing the order of integration (picture included!)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I want to reverse the order of integration. I think region over which we are integrating is like that (as shown in picture).

So, I split it into two cases. First is region from 0 to 1 and second is region from -1/2 to 0.

However,  second integration gives me wrong answer. Where did I make a mistake?[image]

Comment: Your region from $-\frac{1}{2}$ to $0$ is actually $\int^0_{-\frac{1}{2}}\int^0_x$. You might have to separate it into two parts and add a negative sign to the first part.

Comment: why is it from x to 0? I want to integrate with respect to x first. then x must be bounded by some y value..?

Comment: I meant the original integral region. Your picture gives $\int_{-1/2}^0 \int^0_x dydx$, so you have to write your original integral accordingly to your picture. You should switch your x and y after you write it in that way.

Comment: So your original integral should be $-\iint_{A_1}+\iint_{A_2}$ where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are the two regions in your picture. The reason is in region $A_1$, the line $y=x$ is below the line $y=0$. After that, you can switch the two integrals as you did.